# Spring mvc is returning home page after two or more forward slashes

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am learning/developing website in JSP with Sping MVC. The problem now I am facing is that when I try to visit url "localhost/site/about///" it shows default home page, if I go to "localhost/site" it shows home page and if I go to "localhost/about" it shows about page. So I don't know how to throw error page if someone tries to access page with any single forward slash. I mean if I try to access "localhost/site/about/" or "localhost/site/about///" I want my app to throw 404 error page.

Here is my web.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Test</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml file's codes are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.router" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/jsps/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My router file's codes are

```
package com.test.router;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;



@Controller
public class Router {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView homePage(){

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HomePage");

        model.addObject("title", "Welcome to home page");
        model.addObject("msg", "This is the home page.");

        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/about", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView aboutPage(){

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AboutPage");

        model.addObject("title", "About Test website.");

        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loginPage(){

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("accounts");

        model.addObject("title", "Login here to access Test Website.");
        model.addObject("pageTitle", "Login page.");

        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/signup", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView signupPage(){

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("accounts");

        model.addObject("title", "Signup here to join and explore Test Website.");
        model.addObject("pageTitle", "Signup page.");

        return model;

    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView logoutPage(){

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("accounts");

        model.addObject("title", "Logging you out securely.");
        model.addObject("pageTitle", "Logout page.");

        return model;

    }


}
```

So can anyone tell me how can I stop showing default home page after single or multiple forward slashes? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a fallback method to show the error page as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "*")
@ResponseBody
public String errorPage() {
    return "Error page";
}
```

EDIT:

Else you can use regular expression to handle multiple forward slashes at the end:

```
@RequestMapping("{multipleForwardSlashes:[/]{2,}$}")
public String errorPage(@PathVariable String multipleForwardSlashes) {
    return "Error page";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting exception in the code then for specific exceptions you can rendor specific views by using exception resolver.